# 28 out of 34 people prefer product A over product B

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

28 out of 34 people prefer product A over product B.

Can we say that product A is preferred over product B on a 5% level?

If so why or why not? Is this sample size sufficient for our test? What test is best to use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The results are so obvious that you almost do not need a test for this. Anyway, using a proportion test with $\alpha=0.05$ and the null of proportion=0.5 (no difference in proportions between A and B):

```
    1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  28 out of 34, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 12.971, df = 1, p-value = 0.0003164
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6483231 0.9261452
sample estimates:
        p 
0.8235294
```

So the estimated proportion is ~0.82 with a p-value of ~0.0003, so you can safely reject the null hypothesis, A has higher proportion than B.